# How can I write a function in separate class to display alert Box

Tags: android

```
package test;
import test.DisplayAlert;


public class AlertCall
{     int j;

    public int dis2(String phoneNumber)
    {
      DisplayAlert ob = new DisplayAlert();     
      j=ob.dis1(AlertCall.this, phoneNumber);
      return j;
    }
  }
```

**The class to display the dialog box**

```
package test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class DisplayAlert extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
    int t;

        public  int dis(Context activityContext, String destinationAddress)
        {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(activityContext).setTitle("SEND MESSAGE")
               .setMessage("Are you sure you want to send this msg to no ?   "+ destinationAddress)
        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
                { 

                            t=0;
                  }
                })
            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 

                       t=1;
               }
   })
  .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
   .show();
    return t;
}
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    public int dis1(AlertCall alertCall, String phoneNumber) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        new AlertDialog.Builder(alertCall).setTitle("SEND MESSAGE")
           .setMessage("Are you sure you want to send this msg to no ?   "+ phoneNumber)
 .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
         { 

                     t=0;
           }
         })
     .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 

               t=1;
        }
})
.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
.show();
return t;
    }


}
```

I write a class to display Alert Box and call it through separate call but its not working.When I call the function from main_Activity then it is working but if I call from another class then there is an error can anyone please suggest.

Comment: you are creating an instance of Activity class. Make `DisplayAlert` a normal java class. Pass context to the constructor and display dialog.

Comment: Create one BaseActivity extending Activity and put your dialog code there, then in your class extend BaseActivity and you can directly use your dialog.

Comment: I made the changes like`public class AlertCall extends Activity`          and `public int dis1(AlertCall alertCall, String phoneNumber) `         Their is no error but the dialog box is not displayed

Answer (score 7):

Use callbacks

```
public class AlertDialogHelper {

    public static void showAlert(Context context, final Callback callback) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(context).setTitle("Some Title").setMessage("Some message")
                .setPositiveButton("Positive button", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        callback.onSucess(0);
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("Negative button", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        callback.onSucess(-1);
                    }
                }).show();
    }

    public interface Callback {

        public void onSucess(int t);

    }

}


public class AlerCall extends Activity {

    private int j;

    public void dis() {
        AlertDialogHelper.showAlert(this, new AlertDialogHelper.Callback() {

            @Override
            public void onSucess(int t) {
                j = t;
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Our Dialog Class

```
public class MyDialogBuilder 

{
    private Context context;

public AlertDialog getMyDialog(Context c,String message)
{
    this.context=c;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder((Activity)context);
    builder.setMessage(message).setTitle("Download");                               

    builder.setPositiveButton("POSITIVE_BUTTON", new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
        {
        //  do work on positive button press                
        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton("NEGATIVE _BUTTON", new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
        {
        //  do work on negative button press
        }
    });
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    return dialog;

}

}
```

### calling part

```
AlertDialog dialog=new MyDialogBuilder().getMyDialog(Activity_Context,"msg_to_show");
            dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it ll help ypu,if you want to create alert dialog not in mainActivity.

Call this static method in your main activity like this..

```
        AlerBox.showNetworkAlert(MainActivity.this);
```

And in AlertBox Class

```
public class AlerBox {
public static void showNetworkAlert(final Context activity)
{


    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);

    alertDialog.setTitle("KMP");
    alertDialog.setMessage("You don’t seem to have an active internet connection.");

    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            activity.startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS));

        } 
    });



    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


        } 
    });


    alertDialog.show();


}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You must pass context from Activity when call method

Simple solution is

DisplayAlert.java

```
public class AlertDisplay 
{

Context c;
public AlertDisplay(Context context) 
{
    c=context;
}
 public void DiplayAlert(String s)
{
    //Here Code to display alert
}
```

}

Call in main method like

```
AlertDispley ad = new AlertDispley(getApplicationContext())
ad.DiplayAlert("message");
```